# How to use the content of a ipython notebook Markdown cell in python

Tags: python, cell, markdown, ipython, jupyter-notebook

In IPython one can get previous outputs and inputs via `Out[n]` and `In[n]` variables. Is it possible to use the contents of a Markdown notebook cell and use it in python.

I would like to write some text in a Markdown cell

```
This is Markdown I would like to manipulate with.
```

Then I would like to use this text in the next python cell

```
md_cell = ???
print md_cell.replace("Markdown", "Markup")
... # do stuff, write it to a file, be happy
```

to do something with it.

Comment: Not easily, no - the idea is that the kernel doesn't know about the notebook document. People have more often asked for a way to include Python variable values in markdown cells, but that has other complexities.

Comment: I can allways load the notebook file itself with `json.load(open('test.ipynb','r'))` and dig out the right cell. How can I find out the number of current prompt?

Comment: You can, but you have to hardcode the filename. In the kernel, you can get the current execution count (prompt number) with `get_ipython().execution_count`.