# How to copy multiple input cells in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Basically I want to copy (Ctrl+C) only the code portions from multiple cells without also copying the output or the `In[1]:` and `Out[1]:`

What is the easiest way to do so?

Comment: Have you tried clicking one of the cells, and then shift + clicking another cell to get the cell range? I was able to successfully copy and paste those lines of code using this method

Answer (score 47):

When you are on a cell in **Command mode(blue color mode)**, simply press `Shift + DownArrow` or `Shift + UpArrow` to select multiple cells. Press `ctrl + C`. And that's it. You have copied your entire selected code at once. It doesn't affect whether you have cell outputs.

> **Command mode:** The Jupyter Notebook has two different keyboard input modes. Edit mode allows you to type code or text into a cell and is indicated by a green cell border. Command mode binds the keyboard to notebook level commands and is indicated by a grey cell border with a blue left margin.

Comment: Much easier to understand and follow - thanks for providing this alternative answer after two years!

Comment: I tried this. Unfortunately when you do this, and paste them, they all get merged into one cell

Comment: Thank goodness for this answer -- I have wasted so much time copying/pasting individual cells. This should really be part of the standard documentation for notebooks. @KansaiRobot this does not merge cells for me (as of jupyter-notebook version 6.3).

Comment: @KansaiRobot: See an answer below: Now the most important one: make sure the jupyter file you want to copy the cells into is ALSO in blue/command mode. If this is not the case, you will copy all the cells into a single cell.

Answer (score 7):

In jupyter you can copy several cells or the content of one cell. If you follow @BenWS comment you can copy several cells, and if you do `kernel` > `restart & clear outputs` beforehand you woult not get the `[out]`. Shortcut is `C` for copy cell and `V` `shift + V` to paste below / above.

However if you intend to copy several cells content, you should merge then before by select them and shift + M and then you can copy paste with `ctrl + C`.

Comment: it is difficult to understand what did you mean. Command mode? Or Edit mode?

Comment: All the shortcuts are in command mode, you can enter command mode with ESC. Except for the last one ctrl + c you have to be inside the cell

Comment: Shift + M will merge the cells you have selected. Should've at least given a heads up! Now I'm stuck with multiple merged cells that I need to break down again.

Comment: @ahmadPH I mentioned it will merge them in my comment. You can always press Z in command mode if you want to revert

Answer (score 6):

In the latest version of JupyterLabs:

File > Export Notebook As > Executable Script

Gives you the code as a text file.

Comment: @Banik does it highlight just the cells you are interested in in a simple way?

Comment: This is a best answer for those who wish to export the whole code (which is what I was looking for, so I upvoted). OP asked for a different thing though. He/she wanted only a selected code.

Answer (score 5):

What worked for me is the following:

1. update jupyter notebook within a cell using:

   pip install -U jupyter notebook
2. go in command mode by clicking to the left of a cell. If you click inside of a cell, it will be green.
3. Use shift+down/up to select the cells you want to copy and use ctrl+c
4. Now the most important one: make sure the jupyter file you want to copy the cells into is ALSO in blue/command mode. If this is not the case, you will copy all the cells into a single cell.

Answer (score 1):

Just do:
**File > Export Notebook As > Export Notebook to Asciidoc**
and it will be easy to copy paste.
This is what an Asciidoc file looks like:

```
+*In[ ]:*+
[source, ipython3]
----
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("data/survey_results_public.csv")

df.tail(10)

df.shape

pd.set_option("display.max_columns", 85)
pd.set_option("display.max_rows", 85)

schema_df = pd.read_csv("data/survey_results_schema.csv")

schema_df.head(10)


----
```

Answer (score 1):

For jupyterlab after `Shift + UpArrow` or `Shift + select` with mouse on multiple cells. Right click on cells for copy(C) and paste(P).

Answer (score 0):

Open notebook dir as project in PyCharm, and then open the wanted ipynb file, select and copy all the source code, past into notepad++, replace "\r\n#%%\r\n\r\n" by null with extended search mode.

Answer (score 0):

For old Jupyter users
File>Print Preview> ctrl + a

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "old Jupyter" users.

Comment: I'm working on this vesion, its not latest.
jupyter_client   : 7.3.4
jupyter_core     : 4.11.1
jupyter_server   : 1.18.1
jupyterlab       : 3.4.4

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a jupyter notebook in VS Code, then click the three dots "..." in the top-right corner of your notebook,then select "Export" and choose "Python Script". VS Code will automatically create a new python file with all the code (and comments) in it. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Using the menu bar, navigate as follows:

***File -> Save and Export Notebook As -> Executable Script***

This exports your .ipynb Jupyter Notebook code as .py file

In the file, we can copy the whole code at once by doing Ctrl+A and Ctrl+V

Answer (score 0):

#### Programmatic collection of the content of specified code cells

`nbformat` comes as a standard part of Jupyter and so you can run the code examples below in a new Jupyter notebook that is the same directory alongside the Jupyter `.ipynb` file containing the code portions you wish to grab.
`nbformat` has the abstractions of `.ipynb` files & cells & types of cells baked in, and so that makes it very convenient to parse `.ipynb` files progammatically.

For the sake of counting cells, the code below only is concerned with code cells and so markdown & raw cells are not considered. And so this allows you to look at an executed `.ipynb` file **where '`Run All`' had been used to run all cells sequentially top to bottom** and take the numbers from the brackets next to the code cell for what you use as the cell numbers.

Obviously, you can adapt what is done with the collected code text to suit your needs. Currently, the code text is collected in a Python list. In the basic examples provided, I have just added some print statements to illustrate at the conclusion what was collected. Adapt as you see fit.

##### Example 1: Collecting programmatically the input code text from the first '`n`' cells of a notebook

Here is code illustrating collecting the input code from the first '`n`' cells of a notebook. The approach is based on 'Making a notebook from the first n cells of a notebook' from [my answer to 'Jupyter notebook, move cells from one notebook into a new notebook' here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71244733/8508004), as well as the conditional for the code cell type [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73298254/8508004).

```py
number_code_cells_to_keep = 5 # number of first n CODE cells in the input notebook to keep
import nbformat as nbf
ntbk = nbf.read("the_notebook.ipynb", nbf.NO_CONVERT)
nb_code_cells = [cell for cell in (ntbk.cells) if cell.cell_type == 'code']
code_cells_input_code_up_to_limit = [cell.source for indx, cell in enumerate(nb_code_cells) if indx < number_code_cells_to_keep]
for i,each_input in enumerate(code_cells_input_code_up_to_limit):
    print(f"\nContent of code cell #{i+1}:")
    print(each_input)
```

Edit `number_code_cells_to_keep` and the name of the `.ipynb` file appropriately before you run it. **Adjust the setting for '`n`'**, the variable named `number_code_cells_to_keep` in the script, **to some really high value to collect the text of all code cells.**
The resulting list is `code_cells_input_code_up_to_limit` where each item is all the code for a cell.

##### Example 2: Collecting programmatically the input code text from a block of cells at a start point & spanning '`n`' number of cells

Here is code illustrating collecting code text for a block of code cells starting at a specified code cell and continuing for '`n`' more cells. The approach is based on 'Making a notebook from a block of cells at a start point & spanning n number of cells' from [my answer to 'Jupyter notebook, move cells from one notebook into a new notebook' here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71244733/8508004), as well as the conditional for the code cell type [in my answer to 'Finding output cells causing large file size in jupyter notebook' here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73298254/8508004).

```py
cell_to_start_collecting_at = 2 # number of CODE CELL to start the span of CODE CELLS to collect; first cell gets number 1 in bracket if run so use that numbering
total_span_of_code_cells_to_keep = 10 # number of sequential span of CODE CELLS to keep; markdown cells and raw cells do not factor in to count
import nbformat as nbf
ntbk = nbf.read("the_notebook.ipynb", nbf.NO_CONVERT)
nb_code_cells = [cell for cell in (ntbk.cells) if cell.cell_type == 'code']
code_cells_input_code_in_span = [cell.source for indx, cell in enumerate(nb_code_cells) if cell_to_start_collecting_at - 2 < indx < (cell_to_start_collecting_at + total_span_of_code_cells_to_keep - 1)]
for i,each_input in enumerate(code_cells_input_code_in_span):
    print(f"\nContent of code cell #{cell_to_start_collecting_at + i}:")
    print(each_input)
```

Edit `cell_to_start_collecting_at`, the variable `total_span_of_code_cells_to_keep`, and name of the `.ipynb` file appropriately before you run it.
The resulting list is `code_cells_input_code_in_span` where each item is all the code for a cell.