# How can I copy multiple cells from one notebook to another at once (the cells should not merge after pasting)

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

How can I copy multiple cells from one jupyter notebook to another notebook at once, and the cells will not merge after pasting?

I have tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58693806/8366805), in which `shift+Up/Down` are used for selection, `cmd⌘+c` and `cmd⌘+v` are used for copying and pasting. However, the cells will merge after pasting.

Is there a way to prevent the cells from merging?

Comment: I did find the solution at the link worked: weird that it didn't work for you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks for the tips. I tried and found the way not to merge:

1. Press esc key (command mode, the area will turn to blue), 2) use shift+up/down to choose(all turn to blue area) 3) cmd⌘+c to copy
2. Another notebook( you will paste), also press esc key first( that's how not merge) and cmd⌘+v to paste the multi cells, you will get multi cells, including outputs.

Comment: I guess this is for mac, but in windows use `ctrl-c` and `ctrl-v`. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58693806/1886357

Comment: Yes, I use mac. Thanks for the tips for windows.

Answer (score 3):

The cells do not seem to merge, using Jupyter Lab version 2.1.5.

- Click on the left of the top cell you'd like to copy.
- Press the Shift key and click on the bottom cell you'd like to copy.
- The sequence of cells should be highlighted now (in light blue with the usual theme)
- Press the C key to copy
- Select the cell above the cell you want the new cells to appear.
- Press the V key to paste

Result (note that the new cells will have numbers matching the old ones):

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm using jupyter notebook and this doesn't work in jupyter notebook ......

Comment: Jupyter Lab is installed with recent versions of Conda -- try using that if you are able to

Comment: im not sure this helps, but i was able to copy multiple cells in jupyter in vscode in windows using ctrl+left click on the cell's left side, then ctrl+c all of the selection, creating a new cell and then ctrl+v at the left side of that new cell