# github.com notebook cells clipped horizontally and not scrollable

Tags: github, jupyter-notebook

at GitHub.com I am not able to view code/text in jupyter notebook cells that exceed the cell width. I can't find any controls to view the cell contents in full. Am I missing something?

Example:

```py
# This is some very long line that will eventually be clipped leaving the remainder out of view and impossible to read
```

shows as

```py
# This is some very long line that will eventually be clipped leaving the remainder out of vie
```

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, you are indeed missing something, [nbviewer](https://nbviewer.org/) is what you seek.** Or [nbsanity](https://nbsanity.com/).

Look at the third code cell in these two renderings of a notebook and compare:

- [at GitHub](https://github.com/fomightez/bear-classifier/blob/70ee6f58aa9d27fa0deaf9c387c6ca63f2d06bac/bear_classifier.ipynb)
- [rendering the GitHub-hosted `.ipynb` file via nbviewer](https://nbviewer.org/github/fomightez/bear-classifier/blob/70ee6f58aa9d27fa0deaf9c387c6ca63f2d06bac/bear_classifier.ipynb)

You'll see at the second link, you can scroll horizontally to see the text that runs on to the right. I think that shows what you are asking about and why you'd want to use nbviewer.

I should point out there's also [nbsanity](https://nbsanity.com/) by Hamel Husain that is meant to be better than GitHub, too, and has even less cruft.

> "I WAS SO FRUSTRATED with the way @github renders Jupyter Notebooks, esp on mobile (You cannot horizontal scroll code, even with nbviewer). It's different than nbviewer because it uses @quarto_pub as the renderer, which has a more sane way of showing notebooks on different platforms.The upshot is, it will also respect all the quarto directives if that happens to be in your notebook" - Source: Hamel Husain ([here](https://twitter.com/HamelHusain/status/1716266805097070712) and [here](https://twitter.com/HamelHusain/status/1716269213890031905))

(Note that I'm not sure what Hamel means that nbviewer cannot horizontal scroll code since the example I used above shows it will. Maybe he meant on mobile presently?)

---

---

Detailed Explanation about the Jupyter Community-supported solution, Nbviewer:

**Github's rendering of Jupyter `.ipynb` files is provided by them as simple preview of the notebook as a tool for developers.** It is supposed to make it easier to view as a human coder than the code. Simply that. You can think of that similar to how it offers markdown but if you look into details, you'll see it is specifically GitHub-flavored markdown rendering. For `.ipynb` files, for many years GitHub wouldn't render even attempt to render the notebook if it was larger than 100 kb (I think that was the threshold). For reasons that bring you to this question, I wish that was still the case. More on that below. In short, think of the GitHub rendering as nothing as a preview for you the developer.

On the other hand, [nbviewer](https://nbviewer.org/) is the Jupyter community-provided solution for viewing and sharing notebooks in 'static' form. More features, such as scrolling and spanning the fill view are supported by the Jupyter's community offering because the service and software is solely devoted to rendering notebooks, unlike GitHub. Via nbviewer  lot of javascript-based features, like Plotly plots, work in nbviewer's renderings. Plus, the nbviewer renderings aren't embedded inside a GitHub page and thus display with less cruft surrounding them are more inviting for those who aren't developers and **better for sharing with non-developers and stakeholders**.

I wish you had included a link to your notebook with the example you try to put here. You can point nbviewer at your repo yourself by placing the link in the form at [the nbviewer site](https://nbviewer.org/) and see it yourself. I think I may already have an example [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/display-cell-scrollbar-in-jupyter-notebook-on-github/12534/4?u=fomightez). Note that once you figure out the pattern of using GitHub pages with nbviewer, you can make the URL links yourself without the form. There is nothing special about the form; you don't need to use it if you examine URLs previously made with it, you can craft them by hand edits to the GitHub or Gist's URL. The URL simply points nbviewer at places on the internet. You can share these links with anyone.

For more about nbviewer working for Plotly while GitHub doesn't, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73297292/8508004). I have links at the bottom there where you can compare the feature rich rendering via nbviewer as compared to GitHub.

While I appreciate that GitHub has improved their rendering over the years (see #2 listed in 2022 [here](https://twitter.com/HamelHusain/status/1590956886496419840), my opinionated view is that new users used to learn more quickly about nbviewer when GitHub didn't offer the preview for notebooks that were any larger than a few cells because they would seek out a solution. For more on the size of the notebook and rendering on GitHub, see [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/jupyter-notebook-not-rendering-on-github-heres-a-simple-solution-e51aa6ca29b6).

Comment: too bad I then have to leave github which has a ton of features like following declarations and such...the way forward for me would be github just making their cells scrollable, which is all I need personally...

Comment: Take it up with them. In regards to that, I will point out that Hamel Husain who worked there failed to get them to fix that. nbviewer also follows internal document links and links to other files in the associated files if they are made relatively. If I am understanding what you mean.

Comment: Aha, I couldn’t find any linkified words in the output. Are you sure?

Comment: I was talking about relative links in markdown, i.e. [anchor tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16426829/8508004) and links. Can you point to an example of github allowing following declarations in an `.ipynb` file so I know what you are talking about better?