# Turn a jupyter notebook cell into and executable python code

Tags: javascript, python, jupyter-notebook

I usually works in python, within jupyter notebooks. I have this little hacky project where I to scrape code from another notebook and run it. I have managed to do this and run the code with exec() function.

Now I wonder if there is a way 1) to get the code from another cell within the same notebook (say cell above), transform it into a string and run it with exec().

I have heard the way to manipulate cells like this would be to use javascript. But I wouldn't know where to start.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: General advice: If you want a piece of code you want to reuse, convert that into a module (or, better yet, [a package](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/)) and import it whereever you need it.

Comment: @InSync please tell Databricks _et al._ this. When you're in notebooks, this is not at all easy and it leads to, frankly, bizarre ideas like this. The more I'm forced to use notebooks, and see stuff like this, the more depressing it gets

Comment: FWIW where I work now, they use a magic `%run` command to run a different notebook and dump its namespace into the new notebook. At this point, it's splitting hairs about which I hate more - `exec()` on a code string or magic commands

Comment: I am aware this is quite far from good practices (opposite even), but sometimes you have weird constraints.

Comment: You can probably do this without `exec()` as others allude to. Also you can use nbformat to get code as strings from cells in other notebooks. I don't know where you heard the way to do this involved javascript. Always best to cite things because it may have been something different? A lot of older hacks involving javascript don't work in JupyterLab or Jupyter Notebook 7+ because the latter is now built on JupyterLab components. And so such things are fragile. For InSync's advice, ...

Comment: <continued> I'd suggest seeing [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/best-practices-re-reusable-code/22194/2?u=fomightez) and  [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/notebook-alternatives/22405/2?u=fomightez). For more about nbformat, maybe start [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/parsing-the-output-of-a-jupyter-notebook/12524/2?u=fomightez) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76591105/8508004) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73298254/8508004). nbformat has the concepts of notebooks baked in which makes it suitable for parsing specific cell types and making new notebooks ...

Comment: <continues> that you can then run from within another notebook using [jupytext](https://github.com/mwouts/jupytext) or `jupyter nbconvert`. The vague nature of your post makes it hard to provide much specific advice. I'd suggest a toy example of something like you are trying to do in favor of this open ended post. For example, **your title alone is already very feasible with the use of nbformat in conjunction with jupytext**.

Comment: I think my question relates more to formating. That is given a cell with code in the currently running notebook, how do I get the string that would execute similarly.