# Copy & paste a group of cells

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

**Jupyter Notebook**

How can I copy & paste cells from one Jupyter notebook to **another**?

I tried the method that answered [[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46334525/how-to-copy-multiple-input-cells-in-jupyter-notebook/78123424#78123424)], but it did not work for me.

I am learning Python. I am trying to copy and paste my notes from one Jupyter notebook to another.

I am working with various types of cells. Code, Markdowns, and Raw

I use the Jupyter Notebook provided by Anaconda

Can Anyone please help me with that?
Thanks

Comment: The solution you referenced is for only code cells as it was in an answer to 'How to copy multiple input cells in Jupyter Notebook'. You seem to be looking for answers to this question ['Jupyter notebook, move cells from one notebook into a new notebook'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71235359/8508004) because you clearly state you are, "working with various types of cells. Code, Markdowns, and Raw". That code in my answer to [the post there](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71235359/8508004) should allow you to specify a number of cells or blocks of cells to start a new notebook with ...

Comment: <continued>**if you want to do this programmatically.** If your needs are more complex but consistent enough to do programmtically then the code I reference should be a jumping off point to adapt to suit your needs. If what you are doing is to custom/inconsistent each time to do programmatically or you prefer to do it by hand, then I will add you are working a bit with your hands tied behind your back if you aren't using JupyterLab for this. That is highlighted at the bottom of my answer  ....

Comment: <continued> [there under 'Use JupyterLab to drag by hand a sequence of cells to a new notebook'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71244733/8508004).
With JupyterLab, you can have two notebooks open side by side in two frames and you can highlight and select blocks of cells and drag them over to the other. You don't even need to install JupyterLab on your own machine because there's two ways to run it right in your browser right now for doing these two things. See my answer [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/writing-jupyter-notebooks/24453/2?u=fomightez) and follow it to get two options for ...

Comment: <continued> JupyterLab. You won't care what kernel is in use because you'll just be using it to edit. Save the edited file to your machine and run it where you want after moving things. Otherwise with the traditional document-centric Jupyter Notebook interface, you want to duplicate the notebook and then open it in Jupyter to edit to remove the stuff you don't want. I'd be happy to help you more if you need to do this programmatically and the code where I reference now still isn't working for you. My email can be found at my profile page on GitHub which is linked from my StackOverflow profile.

Comment: @Wayne || I really appreciate all the effort you put in this answer. 
I feel like I cannot use Jupyter lab yet. 
I am in my first month of coding ever. So, making a career shift and everything is new to me. I am following a course that uses Jupyter Notebook as the coding environment. The documentation of the course is written with Jupyter Notebook. So, I intend to work with it at the beginning so I can understand what is presented.

Comment: <continued> 
For my notes, I created a separate Jupyter Notebook file for each lecture. Once the lecture is finished, I need to move or copy & paste the notes I wrote from my own training files to the course documentation. 
The course Documentation and my own training files are both written in Jupyter Notebook. 
What I need is just to copy a group of cells from one notebook to another Manually without any programming because it is just too complicated for me at this stage 

**Thanks for your understanding**

Comment: No problem. You don't need to **use** JupyerLab *per se*. You can just open it for editing JupyterLab the ways I provide and edit your documents there with dragging the cells. There's no other easy way. The document-centric interface is made for handling one document at a time. To stick with Jupyter Notebook, uou could use a text editor as your intermediate for collecting the contents using Jupyter Notebook and then copy those to another but you are adding a lot of time copying and pasting the contents. Investing the time to learn how to do this in JupyterLab would be worth it.

Comment: Got you on that. 
Thanks a lot, I will have a look at JupyterLab and try to solve the problem as recommended

Comment: If you look in my profile, there is information about my GitHub account and over there is my email. It may be quicker to do a quick Zoom and show you how to do it.

Comment: Sounds like drag and drop you are doing it correctly!

Comment: Now I am facing a problem of how to actually update JupyterLab and Notebook inside of Anaconda. I found a method of "conda update -c conda-forge jupyterlab" 
I run the command in windows CMD. When I run "conda list" to see if JupyterLab got updated or not, I see that it is marked with "conda-forge".  I don't know what does this mean. I also see in the Anaconda app that the new version is colored with blue and marked updatable, but I don't know if it got updated or not, and what "conda-forge" actually did. 
I feel like I am overwhelmed now 

Comment: `conda-forge` is the channel that developers can control to put out the current best stuff. The main channel is more curated by Anaconda themselves. It will be more slow to be updated and so you may be stuck with a version that has an issue using that channel, longer than using the conda-forge channel. Hopefully you are doing that update in a specific environment. You want to read about Anaconda in the Getting Started they post and leave the base as standard as you can. Changes relative that should be done in an environment.

Comment: That is a good elaboration here. I will check that page if I face any upcoming problems. 
Now I have to ask for a permission now, can I bother you with my questions from time to time when I am stuck at something? 
I am doing the self-taught programmer route within the field of AI. 
And it is so nice to have a mentor **just like you Wayne**.

Comment: I'm happy to help with Jupyter.

Comment: Appreciate it, sounds like a deal!